# Comparing Date to Minimum Future Value in Other Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two django models that define:

Item = A set of items with an expiry date.
Event =  A set of events that have a start and end date.

My aim is that when the item is displayed, its expiry date is shown conditionally formatted, based on whether that item expires after the next event's end date but before the following events end date (so warning when it's due to expire.)

The problem becomes, how best to manage this feat?

If I was directly accessing the database, I'd be using subqueries to get the minimum end date still in the future, and then comparing that to the expiry date on an if basis to swap the formatting.

From research, I'm coming to the conclusion that this is best handled in the view logic, rather than trying to set a method in either of the models, but I don't know how best to get this to splice together so I can return the value of my minimum future date and my itemlist object from the Item model.

The current view is pretty simple at this stage (it will have more filtering options later):

```
def itemlist(request):

        item_list = Item.objects.all
        return render(request, "itemlist.html", {'item_list': item_list})
```

but I cant see a way of easily returning a django equivalent of something like what I'd do in straight SQL:

```
select item from items where status != expired and expiry_date <= (select min(end_date) from events where end_date >= getdate() )
```

EDIT: Since I've written this, I've realised the comparison for what I want is a little more complex, as it's not the minimum date, it's the next to minimum.

For Item A, expiry_date 01/05/19

Event A: end_date 25/04/19 
Event B: end_date 10/05/19

What I need it to do is check the events when reading back the item list, see that Item A's expiry date is after the next event.end_date for event A, but is before the event.end_date for event B, so set a flag for using conditional formatting on the template's expiry date display.

Eventually, I suppose, the wish list is to also be able to say for every item "what's the latest event I can renew this item before it expires if there's an event in the list after its expiry time."

Comment: how `Item` and `Event` models are related?

Comment: They are two separate models at this stage, not directly related in any way. Items and events only interact when you need the item listing logic to check  Item.expiry_date date against the next chronologcal event.end_date that is in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not completely understand your requiremets from your description, but you can use subqueries in Django as well. If you filter like this:

```
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
Item.objects.annotate(last_event_time=Subquery(Event.objects.filter(end_date__gt=now).values('end_date').order_by('-end_date')[:1]))
```

Each item in the resulting queryset will have **last_event_time** field, which would keep the latest event **end_date** field.

You can also use this field in further filtering, using F expressions:

```
Item.objects.annotate(last_event_time=Subquery(Event.objects.filter(end_date__gt=now).values('end_date').order_by('-end_date')[:1])).filter(expiry_date__lte=F('last_event_time'))
```